# Increasing the dimensionality of an array using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I am a beginner in machine learning and I have been researching quite a few methods on how to increase the dimension of an array in python using machine learning techniques. I have come across principal component analysis and Kernel trick which is used for dimensionality reduction. However, I am struggling to find an algorithm which increases the dimensionality of an array.

Suppose I have a numpy array X with shape (20,) and a label vector L = [0,1,....,9] . I am currently using the following equation to conclude with a output array Y of shape (20,10).

[image]

The following code explains it more clearly:

```
import numpy
numLabels = 10

#define input array
X = numpy.random.rand(20,)

#define offset
offset = numpy.full((20,),0.07) 

#define output array
Y = numpy.zeros((20,numLabels))

for l in range(numLabels):
    Y[:,l] = X + (l-4.5)*offset # 4.5 because that the median for numbers 0 to 10
```

The above method however assumes a random offset value to get an output array of shape (20,10).

1) Are there any other ways to get output array Y using the same input array X,  discrete label vector L and real valued offset vector? Possibly some changes in above formula?

2) Are there any other methods to get the output array Y without using a real value offset vector ?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking - are you looking for alternate ways to implement that formula?  Try providing code that generates sample input, and show your current implementation and desired output.

Comment: @andrew_reece Thanks for your comment. I have modified my question into two separate parts. I have also added a sample code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [476]: x = np.random.rand(20,)

In [477]: l = np.arange(10)

In [478]: offset = 0.07

In [479]: Y = x[:,None] + (l - 4.5)*offset

In [480]: Y.shape
Out[480]: (20, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you have simplified the code. However, could you think of any other formula which might or might not use an offset?

Comment: I have an image of 640*480 dimension and my motive is to segment this image using discrete graphical model using OpenGM python package. Each pixel has 20 different intensities which I termed X in the question. Now I want to have (20,10) values for each pixel which I will feed in the OpenGM for running MRF MAP inference. For this I have used discrete input label vector L having 10 values from 0 to 9. After successful inference, each pixel will be segmented into one of the label numbers.